# Metaprogramming for binary functions in DolphinDB

Tags: metaprogramming, dolphindb

When I handled a SELECT statement involving a binary function, such as `select func(a,b) from tb`, the `sqlCol` function can not be used. Does anyone know any alternative metaprogramming techniques available to address this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sqlColAlias`, which accepts a metacode as an argument. To generate metacode for a binary function, you can use the `makeUnifiedCall` or `makeCall` functions.

Note: when using column names as arguments, you need to convert them to column objects using `sqlCol` first.

```
sql(select=sqlColAlias(makeUnifiedCall(funcByName("corr"), [sqlCol("a"), sqlCol("b")])), from="t")
```